# security user registration django rest endpoint

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to implement a user registration endpoint using django rest framework. The endpoint would be public and anyone could potentially register a new user to be able to access the restricted version of the site. The registration endpoint would take a POST action and a JSON object containing let's say first name, last name, email and password. The problem is because of the nature of the endpoint being public someone could program a pyCurl script to create a bunch of new users, I want to avoid that. How can I secure my endpoint properly to avoid that? I have no idea at the moment on what course of action to take. I could make a registration page using CSRF and a django template. That could be a solution and let the rest of the application could run under angular2. Ideally I want to avoid that.

any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to validate the email of the newly registered users. The created users would be set to inactive until they have validated their email address. 
The validation can be done by sending a link containing a token and a UID (see the PasswordResetTokenGenerator from django) at their email address. By following this link, the user can activate his account and login to your site.

As for CSRF, you should always use it when sending data to your server (post, put, patch, etc)